# React Native 0.40 #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h> doesn't find the file for build configuration other than Debug

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

Let's say that I create a new Build Configuration "Debug Copy" that is actually a copy from "Debug" configuration.
If I select "Debug" configuration all is working fine(project compiles), but if I select "Debug Copy" project doesn't compile with error 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found.
I need multiple build configuration and in the version 0.39 all was working fine.

[Link to Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12077/)

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a 0.41 RN new project and i deleted node_modules and did a fresh npm install, and it started working again.

Comment: tried this on react-native version 0.41.2 nogo... any suggestions guys? thanks

Comment: I'm having this same issue with RN 0.44. Removed node_modules, reset caches, reset watchman, none of it fixes it.

Comment: Same issue here.